# Iterate over and call closures in FnMut vector

Tags: loops, closures, rust

I have a `struct` similar to this:

```
struct Foo<'a> {
    callbacks: Vec<&'a FnMut(u32)>,
}
```

I want to call each callback, but my attempt doesn't work:

```
fn foo(&mut self) {
    for f in &mut self.callbacks {
        (*f)(0);
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
error: cannot borrow immutable borrowed content `**f` as mutable
```

I also tried `iter_mut()` but I get the same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`FnMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.FnMut.html) takes a mutable receiver, so you must have a mutable reference to call it:

```
struct Foo<'a> {
    callbacks: Vec<&'a mut FnMut(u32)>,
}
```

Comment: Thanks. To be honest I tried that at one point, but had my doubts because of another error (now fixed) and also because it looked strange. Where can I learn more about receivers?

Comment: Receiver is the name used for the `self` parameter in the description of `Fn`, `FnMut` and `FnOnce` traits. You can read about the self parameter in [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/method-syntax.html).

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase. What is `self` in the context of a closure? Is it the enclosing environment?

Comment: Sorry for my confusion. For a closure,  yes, self is the context of the closure. You can also implement `FnMut` trait for any struct (although it is not stable), in this case, `self` is a mutable reference to a instance of the struct, like in others trait implementations.